# How to iterate the JavaRDD using foreach and find the particular element from each line using spark java

Tags: java, apache-spark

I'm having these lines in my text file:

```
Some different lines....

Name : Praveen  
Age : 24  
Contact : 1234567890  
Location : India  

Some different lines....

Name : John  
Contact : 1234567890  
Location : UK  

Some different lines....  

Name : Joe  
Age : 54  
Contact : 1234567890  
Location : US
```

Some different lines indicates there is some other information in between.

Now I need to read the file and extract the person info. If any key is missing it should be read as empty string (Age is missing in the second person info).

```
JavaRDD<String> data = jsc.textFile("person.report");

List<String> name = data.filter(f -> f.contains("Name")).collect();
List<String> age = data.filter(f -> f.contains("Age")).collect();
List<String> contact = data.filter(f -> f.contains("Contact")).collect();
List<String> location = data.filter(f -> f.contains("Location")).collect();
```

When I do in the above way and iterate over a for loop, the age of 3rd person is getting assigned to 2nd person.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you are collecting everything on the driver, are you sure that's what you want to do? It will not work with a big dataset...

Basically, your problem is that what you consider to be a record is not on a single line. By default, spark considers each line to be a separate record. Yet here, your records are on several lines (name, age, location...). To overcome this, you need to find another delimiter. If in "Some different lines", there is a specific string, use that and set this property:

```
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("textinputformat.record.delimiter","specific string")
```

Then you could write something like:

```
val cols = Seq("Name","Age", "Contact", "Location")
sc.textFile("...")
  .map( _.split("\n"))
  .map(x => cols
       .map( col => x.find(_.startsWith(col)).getOrElse(col+" :") ) )
```

All the lines corresponding to a person will be in the same record for you to process as you wish. If you cannot find any suitable delimiter, your records might all have a Name so you could probably use "Name : ".

In java8 you can use streams to implement it the same way. This is a bit more verbose but since the question was asked for java, there you go:

```
String[] array = {"Name", "Age", "Contact", "Location"};
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(array);
sc.textFile("...")
    .map(x -> Arrays.asList(x.split("\n")))
    .map(x -> list.stream()
                  .map(col -> x.stream()
                               .filter(line -> line.startsWith(col))
                               .findAny()
                               .orElse(col+" :"))
                  .collect(Collectors.toList()) );
```

Comment: i don`t have knowledge on scala, If you have any java code please share it

Comment: I added a java version following the same logic. Do you get the idea of changing textinputformat.record.delimiter though? That's what really matters.

Comment: is it possible without delimiter ??